# Only one selected checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

I have 15 check boxes in a form. This checkboxes are independent to eachother.
I want a javascript function that makes, when user is selecting 2 checkboxes, the first checked box be unchecked and the second remain checked.

Comment: http://www.useit.com/alertbox/20040927.html ?

Comment: If they're independent of each other why're you making them interdependent, and replicating a radio input? What happens without JavaScript being available to enforce this behaviour?

Comment: Use radio buttons instead and give them the same name. Also better for user interface, so he won't be confused -  that's the purpose of radio buttons.

Comment: Check this.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/39405056/2545270

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Would you be better off using radio buttons instead of checkboxes as per this site: http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms10.htm?

If you want to use check boxes I guess you could do something like this:

HTML Code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Check1" value="Value1" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this.id)" /> Option 1
<input type="checkbox" id="Check2" value="Value1" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this.id)" /> Option 2
<input type="checkbox" id="Check3" value="Value1" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this.id)" /> Option 3
<input type="checkbox" id="Check4" value="Value1" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this.id)" /> Option 4
```

Javascript Code :

```
function selectOnlyThis(id) {
    for (var i = 1;i <= 4; i++)
    {
        document.getElementById("Check" + i).checked = false;
    }
    document.getElementById(id).checked = true;
}
```

Comment: I believe it should be  for (var i = 1;i <=4; i++)

Comment: It certainly should. I have modified the code snippet accordingly, thanks :)

Answer (score 9):

### [Check Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/niisar/0hxrgruq/)

1. Give name of you checkboxs let 'myCheckbox'.
2. On click of checkbox loop through all checkbox with name 'myCheckbox';
3. make 'myCheckbox' `uncheck`.
4. make Clicked Checkbox `checked`.

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" value="1" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this)" />
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" value="2" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this)"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" value="3" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this)"/>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function selectOnlyThis(id){
  var myCheckbox = document.getElementsByName("myCheckbox");
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(myCheckbox,function(el){
    el.checked = false;
  });
  id.checked = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I created this CodePen off of John's answer, but I added the ability to uncheck all checkboxes.

HTML:

```
<br />
<br />

<div class="container">
  <div class="field">
    <p class="control">
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="Check1" value="Value1" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this.id)" /> Option 1
  </label>
</p>
    <p class="control">
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="Check2" value="Value1" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this.id)" /> Option 2
  </label>
</p>
<p class="control">
  <label class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" id="Check3" value="Value1" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this.id)" /> Option 3
  </label>
</p>
<p class="control">
  <label class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" id="Check4" value="Value1" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this.id)" /> Option 4
  </label>
</p>
```

JavaScript:

```
function selectOnlyThis(id) {
for (var i = 1;i <= 4; i++){
    if ("Check" + i === id && document.getElementById("Check" + i).checked === true){
            document.getElementById("Check" + i).checked = true;
            } else {
              document.getElementById("Check" + i).checked = false;
            }
    }  
}
```

https://codepen.io/thomasweld/pen/Pmaega?editors=1010

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>

<head>
<title>FooBar</title>
<script language="javascript">
function checkOnly(stayChecked)
  {
  with(document.myForm)
    {
    for(i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
      {
      if(elements[i].checked == true && elements[i].name != stayChecked.name)
        {
        elements[i].checked = false;
        }
      }
    }
  }        
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="myForm">
<input type="checkbox" name="cb1" value="1" onclick="checkOnly(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="cb2" value="1" onclick="checkOnly(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="cb3" value="1" onclick="checkOnly(this)">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

credits to: http://forums.devshed.com/html-programming-1/make-checkboxes-exclusive-55312.html

Comment: Would be simpler expressed as `if (elements[i] != stayChecked && elements[i].checked) elements[i].checked=false` Also stayChecked has an attribute of form that is better used than document.myForm

Answer (score 1):

What you can do instead is to use input type radio and set a common name for all of them. If you try to check another, it will automatically uncheck first one.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other<br><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

At least this is simpler

Answer (score 1):

This way you will have only one checked box and you can uncheck that checked box aswell.

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="CheckId1" onchange="oneCheckedBox(this.id)" /> 
<input type="checkbox" id="CheckId2" onchange="oneCheckedBox(this.id)" /> 
<input type="checkbox" id="CheckId3" onchange="oneCheckedBox(this.id)" /> 
<input type="checkbox" id="CheckId4" onchange="oneCheckedBox(this.id)" />
```

**Javascript**

```
function oneCheckedBox(checkbox_id) {
    if (document.getElementById(checkbox_id).checked) {
        for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
            document.getElementById("CheckId"+i).checked = false;
        }
        document.getElementById(checkbox_id).checked = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be probably checked like this ...

```
          <script type="text/javascript">
                  var call = function(obj){
                  var res=obj.value;
                  obj.checked=true;

                  for(var i=1;i<=3;i++)
                  {
                       if(document.getElementById("check"+i).value!=res )
                       {
                        document.getElementById("check"+i).checked=false;
                       }
                  }
                                          }
          </script>
```

```
<body>

 <input type="checkbox" value="check1" size="46" id="check1" onclick="call(this)"/>

 <input type="checkbox" value="check2" size="46" id="check2" onclick="call(this)"/>

 <input type="checkbox" value="check3" size="46" id="check3" onclick="call(this)"/>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier to use radio buttons rather than a checkbox. That way you can select only one option at a time which is what you want really.

Answer (score 0):

Can check like this:

At javascript:

```
function call(no, value) {
    if(no== 0){
        document.frmMTR.check2.checked = false
        document.frmMTR.check3.checked = false;     
    }
    else if(no== 1){
        document.frmMTR.check1.checked = false
        document.frmMTR.check3.checked = false; 
    }
    else if(no== 2){
        document.frmMTR.check1.checked = false
        document.frmMTR.check2.checked = false; 
    }
}
```

At html:

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="check1" size="46" id="check1" onclick="call(0,this)"/>
 <input type="checkbox" name="check2" size="46" id="check2" onclick="call(1,this)"/>
 <input type="checkbox" name="check3" size="46" id="check3" onclick="call(2,this)"/>
```