# Problem when executing jQuery function via onclick on checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Spanish" <?php if($_GET['set'] == 'Spanish') echo 'checked'; ?> onclick="filter(this)" id="spanish">
<input type="checkbox" value="English" <?php if($_GET['set'] == 'English') echo 'checked'; ?> onclick="filter(this)" id="english">
<input type="checkbox" value="French" <?php if($_GET['set'] == 'French') echo 'checked'; ?> onclick="filter(this)" id="french">

function get_url() {
    var urlPrefix   = '<?php echo site_url('home/language?'); ?>'
    var urlSuffix = "";
    var slectedCategory = "";

    $('#spanish:checked').each(function() {
        slectedCategory = $(this).attr('value');
    });

    $('#english:checked').each(function() {
        slectedCategory = $(this).attr('value');
    });

    $('#french:checked').each(function() {
        slectedCategory = $(this).attr('value');
    });

    urlSuffix = "set="+slectedCategory;
    var url = urlPrefix+urlSuffix;
    return url;
}
function filter() {
    var url = get_url();
    window.location.replace(url);
}
```

The problem that occurs is that when I select the first option (spanish) it works, if I check the second option it also works (english). But if I try to check the previous option again (spanish) it doesn't work.

What can it be? It seems that it works only by going down.

Comment: Should only one checkbox be checked at a time? If so, radio buttons (`type="radio"`) are much better suited to the task.

Comment: No, the user can select two options if desired.

Comment: Well, the code doesn't handle multiple values. `slectedCategory` will only ever have the value of the checked checkbox that is last in source order.

Comment: Hm.. I don't have a lot of knowledge, so that must be why it never worked when selecting two options. Can you give me an option to work the way it does now? With only one selection, and with checkbox.

Comment: What format are you expecting for multiple values?

Comment: In fact, I believe that I will no longer need multiple selection, just one selection.

Comment: There are a few questions about using checkboxes like radio buttons: [Only one selected checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6724064/215552), for instance.

Comment: Note that your code already works with one selected checkbox, as long as the user remembers to uncheck any other checkbox before checking a different one. Some of the answers to the question I linked to shows how to enforce that programmatically.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yes exactly, what I need is that the user can select another option without having to deselect the previous one.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I believe so, but I don't know exactly how to implement this in my current code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is occurring because you didn't work with the value of the clicked checkbox to generate new url in `get_url` function. Replace your js functions like below. It will work.

```
function get_url(elem) {
    var urlPrefix   = '<?php echo site_url('home/language?'); ?>'
    var urlSuffix = "";
    var slectedCategory = "";

    slectedCategory = $(elem).attr('value');

    urlSuffix = "set="+slectedCategory;
    var url = urlPrefix+urlSuffix;
    return url;
}
function filter(elem) {
    var url = get_url(elem);
    window.location.replace(url);
}
```